# pandasで数列の各値を一定区間のstdevを計算してそれで割り算したいとき

Tags: python3, pandas, google-colaboratory

いつもお世話になっております。

【背景】
株の価格をpriceに格納して、そのsmaを窓関数を使って以下のように求めてます

```
sma8 =  pd.Series(price).rolling(8).mean().values
sma24 =  pd.Series(price).rolling(8).mean().values
```

【やりたいこと】
概念のようなものを書きます。

```
sma20_std =  pd.Series(price).rolling(20).std().values
Zscore = (price - sma20) / sma20_std
```

のように、sma（移動平均線）との差をさらに標準偏差（過去20本足分）で割ったものを計算したいと思っています。
Zscoreが一定以上であれば買う・売るといったインジケータを作成しようと考えております。

もちろん上記はエラーを吐き出す正しくないコードなので、適切な書き方を探しているのですが、それらしき文献にたどり着けておりません。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: `sma24` は `rolling(24)` でしょうか？ `sma20` も同様に `rolling(20)` でしょうか？ … その場合エラーにはならないけど, 何かが違うのでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。先ほど再度実行したところ、うまく計算できました。私の勘違いだったようです！大変お騒がせしました……

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
上記のコードに誤りはありません。私のケアレスミスが原因のエラーでした。
大変お騒がせいたしました。